# Sudo does not find new python version

Tags: python, linux

I had python2.6 on my linux box but installed python3.4 to use new modules. I installed it using sudo access. The new version was installed in `/usr/local/bin`. Without root access, I can use the new python3.4, both by just using python3.4 in the command line or using the shebang in the .py file `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Now I am trying to install a module, for which I need sudo access. When I am root, and I run `python3.4`, it says `command not found`. I ran `whereis python` and found the path to python2.6 in `/usr/bin`, but `whereis python3.4` as root gives, `not found in /usr/bin`, which is correct since it is in `/usr/local/bin`. Again, if I exit from root, I have no trouble using python3.4

This seems like a `$PATH` issue (not sure), can some one help me what I am doing wrong while installing the module for the new python3.4? I was able to install the module, but it was installed in the old python2.6 site-packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `export PATH+=:/usr/local/bin`, try it, maybe helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could have given the location to install Py 3.4 to be in /usr/bin.

An easy approach could be to copy the Py 3.4 bin to /usr/bin from /usr/local/bin.

Secondly You can also install again with the prefix params.

Comment: Or you could symlink to it in /usr/bin if you want to leave the actual file in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

The pithonic way to go about handling multiple-interpreters and multiple-library coexistence is by [using virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). These allow you to create a dedicated Python workspace in which you can install the libraries, and the interpreter needed for a given project. In this way you keep projects, *and their dependencies*, separated and avoid having to do horrific things like symbolic links to executables forced into your path. Moreover by creating a virtual environment in a directory where you have full access rights will not require you to be root, or sudo, to install packages and such.

Comment: I agree that you want to use virtual environments, however there are situations where you need to have multiple python installs.  For example, in CentOS/RHEL the linux distro requires python2.6 be installed and uses this for yum to work correctly, to get a different version of python you must do a altinstall

Answer (score 0):

You can get the python PATH by using this command
whereis python

and to run with sudo permission
you can use
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.10 filename.py

In my case it was in /usr/local/bin/python3.10